# Setting up Swagger UI with Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am currently in the process of setting up a Swagger UI interface for one of the projects I am working on and I am experiencing various issues.

My project uses Spring security to secure the API calls using bearer token authentication, so I need to provide a way of enabling the input dialog so that users can input their bearer token. I have tried everything mentioned in the documentation of OpenAPI regarding this but nothing seems to work in rendering the dialog correctly.

Secondly the project does CSRF checks and even though my application properties include `springdoc.swagger-ui.csrf.enabled=true` the check fails constantly. I have a dead end and I have no idea how to resolve both problems. For reference my security configuration is the following:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity security) {
        if (securityProperties.isEnabled()) {
            return security
                    .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(securityProperties.getIgnoredPaths())))
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                    .and()
                    .cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeExchange(spec -> spec.anyExchange().authenticated())
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity.OAuth2ResourceServerSpec::jwt)
                    .build();
        }
        return security
                .securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/**"))
                .authorizeExchange(spec -> spec.anyExchange().permitAll())
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it with our multi-provider (OAuth2 Keycloak for API and Basic Auth for  Swagger UI) Webflux security configuration by adding this to every `application.yaml`:

```yaml
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: true
  swagger-ui:
    oauth:
      client-id: dev
      client-secret: 123
      scopes: [openid]
    csrf:
      enabled: false
```

Key point here is `csrf.enabled: false`.

Our Keycloak security configuration:

```java
// Keycloak-based JWT authorization for @RestControllers
@Order(1)
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfig {
  @Bean("jwt")
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/api/**")
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(grantedAuthoritiesExtractor());

    return http.build();
  }

  private Converter<Jwt, ? extends Mono<? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>>
      grantedAuthoritiesExtractor() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor());

    return new ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
  }
}
```